# Why does space appear in execution result?

Tags: c++

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char *data = new char[20];
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        cin >> (data+i*10);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        if(*(data+i) == '\n'){
            cout << " newline ";
        }else{
            cout << *(data+i);
        }
    }
    int test = static_cast<int>(*(data+9));
    cout << "this is a test " <<  test;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

My input is like this:

```
123456789
123456789
```

Execution is like this:

```
123456789
123456789
123456789 123456789 this is a test 0 . . .
```

The variable `test` is 0. And space in ASCII is 32 in decimal.

Why is there two spaces (first space between 9 and 1, second space between 9 and t) in my execution result?

Comment: Its for + and - I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those aren't space characters.  They are the unprintable character `'\0'`.

Note that cppreference says of the function [`std::operator>>(std::istream&, char*)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2) (function #2 at that page):

> The whitespace character is not extracted.

and

> An additional null character value `CharT()` is stored at the end of the output.

So when `operator>>` encountered the newline characters in your input, it wrote null characters to `data[9]` and `data[19]`.  The effect of printing that out depends on your terminal; apparently yours makes it look like a space.

But note that this function extracting into a `char*` is very dangerous, because it can go past the end of valid storage.  In particular, please NEVER use this function with `std::cin` in real code, since you can't stop a user from inputting more than you allocated for.  Instead, create a `std::string` and input into that, which will automatically grow the string as necessary.

Comment: "In particular, please NEVER use this function with `std::cin` in real code, since you can't stop a user from inputting more than you allocated for." That is not true: `char input[10]; std::cin >> std::setw(sizeof(input)) >> input;`